# Running make for Nginx throws a “multiple target patterns” error

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, make, linux

When I run `make` inside my installed nginx directory I get the output:

```
make -f objs/Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/nginx/nginx-1.2.4'
objs/Makefile:110: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/nginx/nginx-1.2.4'
```

make: *** [build] Error 2

I am on an Amazon Linux AMI.

The steps I took from the beginning was

```
wget /path/to/nginx/tarball
tar xvf nginx-1.2.4.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.2.4
./configure --prefix=/nginx --a-bunch-of-other-options
```

Then I ran `make`.

Also I installed `make` by running `sudo yum install make`

Please let me know if there's any other information I should be providing.

Comment: please paste the full log of your failed build

Comment: @Hex ok the full output is there

Comment: If you are not using custom parameters for your Nginx build, you may find it much easier to just install Nginx binary from the Nginx repository. The options used are good for most installations (with the added advantage of updates being easily installable). If you are interested, instructions for setting up the Nginx repository can be found on the [Nginx Wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Official_Red_Hat.2FCentOS_packages) (For Amazon's Linux, use the instructions you would for CentOS6).

Comment: @cyberx86 yeah I ended up installing it through `yum`

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a variable in objs/Makefile on line 110 which contains a colon -- e.g. as part of a filename.  See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100448/multiple-target-patterns-makefile-error
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401976/very-simple-application-fails-with-multiple-target-patterns-from-eclipse